# Motion in a central field in Landau Mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics

[image]

What does this mean when E=U_eff?
I don't think this means the first term in E is zero. I don't understand the sentence ' This is a cubic equation for cos(theta)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means there is an asymptote for
$$
E=U_{eff}(\theta)
$$
which corresponds to a certain value of $\theta$ you can evaluate by solving the equation:
$$
E=\frac{M_z^2}{2ml^2}\sin^2{\theta}-mgl\cos{\theta}
$$
So $E$ takes this value in a infinite time.
This equation is quadratic in $\cos{\theta}$ also because it's written that there are 2 roots. Maybe it's a misprint.

Comment: Hi @Giuseppe Galesi, just a note: the time needed to obtain $U_{\text{eff}} (\theta ) = E$ needs not to be infinite - indeed, it's infinite if and only if the inversion point is an equilibrium point ($\frac {dU}{d\theta}=0$).